# Redux + socket.io in the server - Does business logic belong in event listeners or action creators?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, redux

I'm implementing an online multiplayer game which will receive connections from clients through socket.io.

I'm not sure where to handle events in the server - either in the socket event listeners themselves, or if they should defer this logic to the action creators.

Take into account that in many of the cases, receiving an event from a client socket will trigger an `.emit` or `.broadcast` from the server side, so I need to have access to `socket` and `io` inside whatever function handles this.

**My solution so far:**

Store creator:

```
export default io => createStore(
    combineReducers({
        users,
        tables,
        games
    }),
    applyMiddleware(
        thunk.withExtraArgument(io),
        logger
    )
);
```

Create store with `io` as an extra thunk argument, so that action creators can `io.emit` events, bind socket event handlers to `store` and `io` so that they can `dispatch`, `getState` and `io.emit`:

```
let store = createStore(io),
    //socket event handlers
    boundHandlers = [
        tables,
        games,
        messages
    ].map(handler => handler(store, io));

io.on('connect', users(store, io, boundHandlers));
```

My `users` higher order function that returns the event handler for incoming connections and registers the `boundHandlers` declared previously:

```
let connections = {};

export default ({dispatch, getState}, io, handlers) => async socket => {
    //close sockets with same session id
    let sessionId = socket.handshake.session.id;

    if(connections[sessionId])
        connections[sessionId].disconnect();

    connections[sessionId] = socket;

    let userId = /** some authentication logic here **/

    //bind event handlers to socket
    handlers.forEach(handler => handler(socket, userId));

    socket
    //send initial user state
    .emit('init', userId, getUserState(getState(), userId))

    /** other stuff **/
}
```

This last piece of code is the one I'm not sure should be in the event listener or in an action creator.

Answer (score -1):

In idiomatic redux action creators should be pure (no side effects) which means keeping them free of asynchronous logic.

I wrote middleware to configure the connection and dispatch actions accordingly.

I'd recommend checking out one of the number of libraries that are out there for this. Either to use as is or for ideas on how to implement your own. Like [socket.io-redux](https://github.com/PlatziDev/socket.io-redux).

Comment: Ah... you mean _reducers_ should be pure and free of asynchronous logic.  Action creators and middleware are where side effects usually live,

Comment: I can't really see the usefulness of a middleware in this case. Meanwhile I've reached the conclusion that all code pertaining to receiving/sending messages from/to the client should be in the socket event listeners and business logic should be in the action creators. Does that seem reasonable?

Comment: I guess the first question is, what are you defining as "business logic"?  FWIW, there's a [Redux FAQ entry on "splitting business logic between action creators and reducers"](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/CodeStructure.html#structure-business-logic).  Second, middleware are the right place for interacting with sockets in Redux, because they form a persistent location with access to `dispatch`, `getState`, and the dispatch pipeline. There's dozens of existing socket middlewares - see https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/middleware-sockets-adapters.md .

Comment: `io.on('connect')` for example. When a client connects, I have to authenticate them and retrieve their session (in case connection dropped or something). Does this logic happen inside the 'connect' event listener, or does it simply call a `userConnect` action creator that handles it?

Comment: In other words, what is the difference between piping a socket event right away to `dispatch` and handling it in the middleware, having the event listeners handle the logic and dispatch a skinny action creator, or having the event listeners call a fat action creator that handles the logic for them and dispatches?